# how to tell which non-terminal is missing within an expansion in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

```
oC_RangeLiteral
            :  '*' SP? ( oC_IntegerLiteral SP? )? ( '..' SP? ( oC_IntegerLiteral SP? )? )? ;
```

Given a parser tree with `ctx->oC_IntegerLiteral().size() == 1`, How can I tell whether the first one is missing or the second one is missing?

Maybe the question title can be improved based on this concrete question.

Answer (score 2):

You can [label rule elements](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-element-labels) with `name =`  like this:

```
oC_RangeLiteral
 :  '*' SP? 
    ( first=oC_IntegerLiteral SP? )? 
    ( '..' SP? ( second=oC_IntegerLiteral SP? )? )? 
 ;
```

Not sure how to use them with the C++ runtime, but for, say, Java, that'd look like this:

```java
if (ctx.first != null) {
  // 'first' exists
}

if (ctx.second != null) {
  // 'second' exists
}
```

#### EDIT

> Is it possible to achieve similar without modifying the grammar?

Sure, but that makes it a lot messier. You'd need to figure out if there is a `..` among the children of `oC_RangeLiteral` and then check if the `oC_IntegerLiteral` comes before or after this `..` token. Something like this:

```java
// Only need to check if 1 child is present: in case of 2 or 0 children, it is clear
if (ctx.oC_IntegerLiteral().size() == 1) {

  int indexOfIntegerLiteral = ctx.children.indexOf(ctx.oC_IntegerLiteral().get(0));

  OptionalInt indexOfDotDot = java.util.stream.IntStream
      .range(0, ctx.children.size())
      .filter(i -> ctx.children.get(i).getText().equals(".."))
      .findFirst();

  System.out.printf("indexOfIntegerLiteral=%d\n", indexOfIntegerLiteral);
  System.out.printf("indexOfDotDot=%s\n", indexOfDotDot);

  if (indexOfDotDot.isPresent() && indexOfIntegerLiteral > indexOfDotDot.getAsInt()) {
    // If there is a ".." and the single `oC_IntegerLiteral` comes after it: it's the second one
  }
  else {
    // otherwise, it's the first `oC_IntegerLiteral`
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a good answer. Is it possible to achieve similar without modifying the grammar?

Comment: @cpchung you're welcome. Checkout my **EDIT**

Answer (score 1):

Another way is this:

Give your terminals own token names, say

```
STAR: '*';
DOTDOT: '..';
```

With that your rules becomes:

```
oC_RangeLiteral
            :  STAR SP? ( oC_IntegerLiteral SP? )? ( DOTDOT SP? ( oC_IntegerLiteral SP? )? )? ;
```

Now in your code you just check for `DOTDOT`:

```cpp
if (ctx->oC_IntegerLiteral().size() == 1) {
    if (ctx->DOTDOT()) {
         // ctx->oC_IntegerLiteral(0) is the second integer literal
    } else {
         // ctx->oC_IntegerLiteral(0) is the first integer literal
    }
}
```

As a side note: `ctx->oC_IntegerLiteral().size()` can be 0, because the it's optional in both cases where it appears in the rule. So, just testing the existence of `DOTDOT` does not tell you there's at least one integer literal.